# Why a UIButton could send message to a private method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

In the first case in the book iOS programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, they only implemented a method `- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender` between the `@implementation @end`, but did not declare it in the `@interface @end` in the .h file. As far as I know, if you don't declare methods in the `@interface @end`, the method cannot be accessed from outside. But the truth is the UIButton did send message to the controller instance, that confused me. Do I have a wrong idea about private method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InterfaceBuilder looks in all source files, headers and implementation, to find IBOutlets and IBActions. Private or not, it sees all declared methods, so you can connect them to interface components. During runtime, all methods are equal, so of course the button can call a private method.

Comment: Did this mean that UI instances can send message to a private method because of InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: Anybody can send private messages. There's nothing in the runtime that prevents that. Private access is a pure compile time concept, that is not honored by IB.

Comment: So why should we declare methods in the `@interface @end`, since messages can be sent anyway? Just because the compiler doesn't like it?

Comment: I was surprised to find that you are correct (voted). This behavior changed at some point. It used to only see IBOutlets and IBActions if they were defined in the header, and I got in the habit of always defining my outlets/actions in the header AND the .m file. Do you know which version of Xcode started finding outlets/actions in the .m as well? Maybe Xcode 4.1 or so, when the LLVM compiler became the only compiler?

Comment: You declare methods in your interface to make them as public. Then other classes can call them and the compiler knows how to compile/link the code. If you don't declare a method in your header and try to call it from another class, the compiler will complain that the method is not defined. It will still work if the compiler is able to guess the types of the parameters.

Comment: By convention you should not call methods in other classes unless they are declared in the header. Otherwise you risk that those methods may be changed/deleted in the future, (The header serves as the "contract" for the interface the class supports).

Comment: My Xcode is 6.0.1, and I haven't code for a long time. When I come back, the way of declaring has changed and made me so confused.

Comment: @DuncanC I don't think the change is a result from the switch to LLVM but from IB becoming a part of Xcode (not sure, though). When Interface Builder was still an independent app I remember that I frequently had to explicitly re-read the class headers to access newly added outlets. I think at this time it never looked at implementation files. After becoming a part of Xcode IB got access to the whole project model and could easily find and scan all of a target's source files.

Comment: Nikolai, it was after that, I'm sure of it. I think it may have been as recently as Xcode 5.x.

Comment: @DuncanC Actually, I don't believe so. I'm quite sure that I've been using (private) class extensions for outlet declarations since Xcode 4, which was first released at WWDC 2010. This also happens to be the first release that combined IB into Xcode.